# Editing text causes unity to crash

Tags: unity3d-gui, unity-game-engine

1. What happened

When trying to change the text of a button or text, unity editor crashes.

2. How we can reproduce it using the example you attached

Create a new project.
Add Text (GameObject->UI->Text)
Crash occurs when you click to change the default "New Text" to something else.

Same happens with a button.

Unity Version is 5.1.1f1_2046fc06d4d8

I also tried it on another PC that had no Unity installed before: same result.

What am I doing wrong?

This is the Editor.log stacktrace:

```
========== OUTPUTING STACK TRACE ==================

000007FEEE95AF7E (mono) fmod
  ERROR: SymGetSymFromAddr64, GetLastError: 'Kan opgegeven module niet vinden.' (Address: 000000000A98224A)
  ERROR: SymGetModuleInfo64, GetLastError: 'Een initialisatieroutine van de dynamic link library (DLL-bestand) is mislukt.' (Address: 000000000A98224A)
000000000A98224A ((<unknown>)) 
0000000011C0D1FF (Mono JIT Code) [C:\buildslave\unity\build\artifacts\generated\common\runtime\GUIStyleBindings.gen.cs:781] UnityEngine.GUIStyle:DrawWithTextSelection (UnityEngine.Rect,UnityEngine.GUIContent,int,int,int,bool) 
0000000011C0CED6 (Mono JIT Code) [C:\buildslave\unity\build\artifacts\generated\common\runtime\GUIStyleBindings.gen.cs:804] UnityEngine.GUIStyle:DrawWithTextSelection (UnityEngine.Rect,UnityEngine.GUIContent,int,int,int) 
0000000011C0C702 (Mono JIT Code) [C:\buildslave\unity\build\Runtime\Export\TextEditor.cs:985] UnityEngine.TextEditor:DrawCursor (string) 
000000001ADC1010 (Mono JIT Code) [C:\buildslave\unity\build\Editor\Mono\EditorGUI.cs:903] UnityEditor.EditorGUI:DoTextField (UnityEditor.EditorGUI/RecycledTextEditor,int,UnityEngine.Rect,string,UnityEngine.GUIStyle,string,bool&,bool,bool,bool) 
0000000011BE54A2 (Mono JIT Code) [C:\buildslave\unity\build\Editor\Mono\EditorGUI.cs:1379] UnityEditor.EditorGUI:ScrollableTextAreaInternal (UnityEngine.Rect,string,UnityEngine.Vector2&,UnityEngine.GUIStyle) 
0000000011BE4175 (Mono JIT Code) [C:\buildslave\unity\build\Editor\Mono\ScriptAttributeGUI\Implementations\PropertyDrawers.cs:76] UnityEditor.TextAreaDrawer:OnGUI (UnityEngine.Rect,UnityEditor.SerializedProperty,UnityEngine.GUIContent) 
0000000011BE3D14 (Mono JIT Code) [C:\buildslave\unity\build\Editor\Mono\ScriptAttributeGUI\PropertyDrawer.cs:23] UnityEditor.PropertyDrawer:OnGUISafe (UnityEngine.Rect,UnityEditor.SerializedProperty,UnityEngine.GUIContent) 
0000000011BA350D (Mono JIT Code) [C:\buildslave\unity\build\Editor\Mono\ScriptAttributeGUI\PropertyHandler.cs:134] UnityEditor.PropertyHandler:OnGUI (UnityEngine.Rect,UnityEditor.SerializedProperty,UnityEngine.GUIContent,bool) 
0000000011BE29ED (Mono JIT Code) [C:\buildslave\unity\build\Editor\Mono\ScriptAttributeGUI\PropertyHandler.cs:195] UnityEditor.PropertyHandler:OnGUILayout (UnityEditor.SerializedProperty,UnityEngine.GUIContent,bool,UnityEngine.GUILayoutOption[]) 
0000000011BDCBEB (Mono JIT Code) [C:\buildslave\unity\build\Editor\Mono\EditorGUI.cs:6811] UnityEditor.EditorGUILayout:PropertyField (UnityEditor.SerializedProperty,UnityEngine.GUIContent,bool,UnityEngine.GUILayoutOption[]) 
0000000011BDCB1A (Mono JIT Code) [C:\buildslave\unity\build\Editor\Mono\EditorGUI.cs:6793] UnityEditor.EditorGUILayout:PropertyField (UnityEditor.SerializedProperty,UnityEngine.GUILayoutOption[]) 
0000000011BDC984 (Mono JIT Code) [C:\buildslave\unity\build\Extensions\guisystem\UnityEditor.UI\UI\TextEditor.cs:33] UnityEditor.UI.TextEditor:OnInspectorGUI () 
0000000011B97ECC (Mono JIT Code) [C:\buildslave\unity\build\Editor\Mono\Inspector\InspectorWindow.cs:1162] UnityEditor.InspectorWindow:DrawEditor (UnityEditor.Editor,int,bool,bool&,UnityEngine.Rect&,bool) 
000000001AE4A704 (Mono JIT Code) [C:\buildslave\unity\build\Editor\Mono\Inspector\InspectorWindow.cs:969] UnityEditor.InspectorWindow:DrawEditors (UnityEditor.Editor[]) 
000000001AE485D9 (Mono JIT Code) [C:\buildslave\unity\build\Editor\Mono\Inspector\InspectorWindow.cs:350] UnityEditor.InspectorWindow:OnGUI () 
00000000176D68E2 (Mono JIT Code) (wrapper runtime-invoke) object:runtime_invoke_void__this__ (object,intptr,intptr,intptr)
000007FEEE914053 (mono) [c:\buildslave\mono-runtime-and-classlibs\build\mono\mini\mini.c:4914] mono_jit_runtime_invoke 
000007FEEE868389 (mono) [c:\buildslave\mono-runtime-and-classlibs\build\mono\metadata\object.c:2623] mono_runtime_invoke 
000007FEEE86E783 (mono) [c:\buildslave\mono-runtime-and-classlibs\build\mono\metadata\object.c:3827] mono_runtime_invoke_array 
000007FEEE82CECB (mono) [c:\buildslave\mono-runtime-and-classlibs\build\mono\metadata\icall.c:2857] ves_icall_InternalInvoke 
00000000176A0217 (Mono JIT Code) (wrapper managed-to-native) System.Reflection.MonoMethod:InternalInvoke (object,object[],System.Exception&)
000000001769E372 (Mono JIT Code) [/Users/builduser/buildslave/mono-runtime-and-classlibs/build/mcs/class/corlib/System.Reflection/MonoMethod.cs:222] System.Reflection.MonoMethod:Invoke (object,System.Reflection.BindingFlags,System.Reflection.Binder,object[],System.Globalization.CultureInfo) 
0000000019EFC1DF (Mono JIT Code) [/Users/builduser/buildslave/mono-runtime-and-classlibs/build/mcs/class/corlib/System.Reflection/MethodBase.cs:115] System.Reflection.MethodBase:Invoke (object,object[]) 
0000000019F66E46 (Mono JIT Code) [C:\buildslave\unity\build\Editor\Mono\HostView.cs:185] UnityEditor.HostView:Invoke (string,object) 
0000000019F66D30 (Mono JIT Code) [C:\buildslave\unity\build\Editor\Mono\HostView.cs:178] UnityEditor.HostView:Invoke (string) 
000000001ADABF22 (Mono JIT Code) [C:\buildslave\unity\build\Editor\Mono\GUI\DockArea.cs:334] UnityEditor.DockArea:OnGUI () 
00000000176D68E2 (Mono JIT Code) (wrapper runtime-invoke) object:runtime_invoke_void__this__ (object,intptr,intptr,intptr)
000007FEEE914053 (mono) [c:\buildslave\mono-runtime-and-classlibs\build\mono\mini\mini.c:4914] mono_jit_runtime_invoke 
000007FEEE868389 (mono) [c:\buildslave\mono-runtime-and-classlibs\build\mono\metadata\object.c:2623] mono_runtime_invoke 
000000014039A04F (Unity) scripting_method_invoke
00000001405596DF (Unity) ScriptingInvocationNoArgs::Invoke
000000014037A5BD (Unity) MonoBehaviour::DoGUI
0000000140E2568D (Unity) GUIView::OnInputEvent
0000000140E26A82 (Unity) GUIView::DoPaint
0000000140E26E40 (Unity) GUIView::RepaintAll
0000000140D2FA11 (Unity) Application::TickTimer
0000000140E41AF4 (Unity) RelaunchUnity
0000000140E430EB (Unity) WinMain
00000001414D2420 (Unity) strerror_s
0000000077535A4D (kernel32) BaseThreadInitThunk
000000007766B831 (ntdll) RtlUserThreadStart

========== END OF STACKTRACE ===========
```

translation : 
'Kan opgegeven module niet vinden.' = 'Cannot find specified module'
'Een initialisatieroutine van de dynamic link library (DLL-bestand) is mislukt.' = 'A dynamic link library (DLL) initialization routine failed.'

So I think it wants a DLL file, but it can't find it. 
Maybe it is because my windows is installed in dutch? Or maybe I need some .net frameworks? I really don't know..

Comment: The same.. and thanks for pointing out to me that there's a new version available. When i checked for updates it said there were no updates.

Comment: Can someone try this and see if it also crashes? This seems like such a basic flaw that I can't believe they didn't notice yet.

Comment: Have you tried looking at your unity crash log? [Where are my unity crash log files](http://docs.unity3d.com/Manual/LogFiles.html) I personally never had this issue before, but seen some reports in unity 4.6.1

Comment: Can't reproduce in 5.1.1p4, and never had such a problem with any version till date.

Comment: I can't reproduce it... there's a 5.1.3p1 now if you want to try that.

Comment: Thanks guys for trying, I added the stack trace from the log file and I am almost sure I am missing a DLL. I don't know which one though.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Run as Administrator

..

I cannot believe I didn't try that.
Thanks to everyone who helped solve this!